# aspxのデザインが表示できない。「ASP.NET、C#」

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net

Visual Studio 2015でWebアプリケーションの開発をしています。
C#、ASP.NET OS：Windows10

数日前に突然aspxのデザインの表示ができなくなってしまいました。
「デザイン」、「並べて表示」を選択するとその開いているファイルのみ固まって、ファイルを閉じる以外できなくなってしまいます。
また、他PCのVisual Studio 2015では問題なく開くことができています。

いろいろ調べてみてはいるのですが解決方法が見つからず困っています。
同じ現象で解決された方いらっしゃいましたら、ご回答いただけると幸いです。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: `AppData`内の`%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`にあるファイルを消すと直る場合があります。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。載せていただいた方法を試してみましたが、改善には至りませんでした。